# Fotoware Index Manager: notification of changes

Tags: fotoware

Fotoware Index Manager detects changes in the file system and updates its index with metadata about the file that has changed.

Is there any way to get Index Manager to send a notification of that event to a URL I specify?

If Index Manager uses SQL Server to store its index, would it be possible to set up a trigger in the database that would send the notification I need?

Answer (score 2):

With the FotoWare suite in version 7.0, you can monitor the log files of Index Manager to learn of new/updated files.

With Version 8.0, which is due to be released early 2014, you will be able to register webhooks to receive notifications of all updates in the archives controlled by Index Manager.